# Giving a lazy_static its proper type in Rust

Tags: static, rust

I have this file `utils.rs` declaring a `lazy_static` like below:

```
extern crate geojson;
extern crate geo;

use self::geo::MultiPolygon;
use self::geojson::GeoJson;
use self::geojson::conversion::TryInto;

lazy_static! {
    pub static ref LAND_POLYGONS: MultiPolygon<f64> = {
        let input_string = include_str!("resources/land.geojson");
        let mut polygons: Vec<Polygon<f64>> = vec![];
        // ...
        // add some polygons here
        // ...
        MultiPolygon(polygons)
    };
}
```

Then in `main.rs` I try to use `LAND_POLYGONS` as follows:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;

extern crate geo;

use self::geo::MultiPolygon;
use utils::LAND_POLYGONS;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<Error>> {
    lazy_static::initialize(&LAND_POLYGONS);
    println!("{:?}", LAND_POLYGONS);

    Ok(())
}
```

Which produces the following compiler error:

```
error[E0277]: `utils::LAND_POLYGONS` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Debug`
  --> src/main.rs:30:22
   |
30 |     println!("{:?}", LAND_POLYGONS);
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `utils::LAND_POLYGONS` cannot be formatted using `:?`; add `#[derive(Debug)]` or manually implement `std::fmt::Debug`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::fmt::Debug` is not implemented for `utils::LAND_POLYGONS`
   = note: required by `std::fmt::Debug::fmt`
```

It seems that `LAND_POLYGONS` is loaded as an instance of its own type.

How to give `LAND_POLYGONS` its proper type, being a `geo::MultiPolygon` instead? As a side note, `MultiPolygon` does indeed definitely implement `Debug`.

The `lazy_static` documentation and examples make it look like this would already be the case without anything special to do.

*Note: when putting all the above into one single `main.rs` file, the result is the same.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Under the hood, lazy_static generates a one-off struct type with a `Deref` implementation which gives you a reference to the actual value of the type you have specified.

Change your `println` statement to this:

```
println!("{:?}", *LAND_POLYGONS);
```

Comment: In case you're using the `dbg!` macro, you might need `&*LAND_POLYGONS` since it doesn't automatically borrow its argument like `println!` does.

Comment: Wouldn't `&*LAND_POLYGONS` result in a `&&MultiPolygon<f64>`, seeing how `deref()` returns a reference already?