# What type should I use to return a lazy_static value?

Tags: rust, lazy-static

I plan to have a struct which provides the JSON schema via a trait method.
The schema is stored compiled in a lazy_static variable, but which type does my `schema()` function have to return?

```
lazy_static::lazy_static! {
    static ref DEF: serde_json::Value = serde_json::json!({
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "name":         { "type": "string",
                            "minLength": 10,
                            },
        },
    });

    static ref SCHEMA: jsonschema::JSONSchema<'static> = jsonschema::JSONSchema::compile(&DEF).unwrap();
}

struct MySchema {
    name: String,
}

impl MySchema {
    pub fn schema() -> jsonschema::JSONSchema<'static> {
        SCHEMA
    }
}

#[test]
pub fn test() {
    let test = serde_json::json!({"name":"test"});
    assert_eq!(SCHEMA.is_valid(&test), false);
    assert_eq!(MySchema::schema().is_valid(&test), false);
}
```

I'll get this error

```
pub fn schema() -> jsonschema::JSONSchema<'static> {
                   ------------------------------- expected `JSONSchema<'static>` because of return type
    SCHEMA
    ^^^^^^ expected struct `JSONSchema`, found struct `SCHEMA`
```

Comment: You can't return an owned value. You can only return a reference to the static variable. Changing the return type to `&jsonschema::JSONSchema<'static>` and the return value to `&*SCHEMA` should work.

Comment: Your question may be answered by [Giving a lazy_static its proper type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50339314/155423) or [Why does a lazy-static value claim to not implement a trait that it clearly implements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48114390/155423)

Comment: @SvenMarnach I had to change the return type to `&'static jsonschema::JSONSchema<'static>` because of error `expected named lifetime parameter, help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value, but there is no value for it to be borrowed from
help: consider using the 'static lifetime`. I'm still learning Rust, and this is the first time I have to use lifetimes. Why do I need it? Isn't the type itself already `'static`, because it's `static ref` ?

Comment: I did already know that a new type is generated by the macro. I already saw one of the above linked answers. But I thought my function has to return somehow this new type and I didn't know, how to name it. Anyway this wouldn't be helpful in my case, because I want to create a trait with this function where I need a common type.

Comment: References in function arguments and return types need lifetime annotations unless one of the [lifetime elision rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-elision) applies. These rules cover some of the most common cases, but not this specific case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I close this question with answer from Sven Marnach:

You can't return an owned value. You can only return a reference to the static variable.
Change return type to `&'static jsonschema::JSONSchema<'static>` and the return value to `&*SCHEMA`.

```
lazy_static::lazy_static! {
    static ref SCHEMA: jsonschema::JSONSchema<'static> = jsonschema::JSONSchema::compile(&DEF).unwrap();
}

impl MySchema {
    pub fn schema() -> &'static jsonschema::JSONSchema<'static> {
        &*SCHEMA
    }
}
```